# sql query join multiple tables

Tags: sql

I want to get all columns from People and adress where CategoryId equals to category.

Have this query.

```
SELECT   
    Category.Id, People.*, Adress.* 
FROM     
    Category 
JOIN 
    People ON People.CategoryId = Category.CategoryId 
JOIN     
    Adress ON Adress.PeopleId = People.Id  
WHERE    
    Category.CategoryId = @category 
ORDER BY 
    People.PeopleId DESC ;
```

Error shows up when I run my application.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Invalid column name 'Id'. Invalid column name 'Id'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column
>   name 'Id'. Invalid column name 'Id'.
>
> Source Error:  Line 153:            da.SelectCommand = command; Line
>   154:            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); Line 155:
>   da.Fill(dt); Line 156:            cn.Close(); Line 157:
>   PagedDataSource pgitems = new PagedDataSource();

Why it does not work ? Some help ?

Using visual studio local database.

Comment: What is not working? Is it syntactically incorrect? Are you getting unexpected results? Please clarify

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I updated my post. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed Id to respective CategoryId and PeopleId

```
SELECT   Category.CategoryId , People.*, Adress.* 
FROM     Category JOIN People ON People.CategoryId=Category.CategoryId 
JOIN     Adress ON Adress.PeopleId=People.PeopleId
WHERE    Category.CategoryId=@category 
ORDER BY People.PeopleId DESC ;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I had problem with constraint key too. 
But now it works perfectly :))

Answer (score 1):

The error is because your table "Category" does not have a column name "Id".  It looks like you need to change that to "CategoryId".

You may also have a similar problem with your People table (no "Id" column).

Comment: Category has column named CategoryId.

Comment: Right--so why are you referencing "Category.Id" in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be on Category.Id, verify if is correct with this uppercase. I think this is something like "Category.id" or "Category.CategoryId"